# Unable to install Ubuntu on external SSD

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 16 (and later 18) on an external SSD drive. It is not my first time to install Ubuntu, but this time I tried to make a portable boot. I formated the SSD first, and tried installing Ubuntu with a USB.

As soon I tried to make a partition in the empty space, I get the following listed:

emptyspace - 33 mb

ext4       - xxxxxx mb (the total size of SSD is 256GB, so the rest is here)

emptyspace - 10 mb

I cannot remove these empty spaces of 33 and 10 mb, but I don't care about that. As I try to continue to install, I get a pop-up saying that there is an offset of 3540 (or something) bytes, which leads to very poor performance. Then it instructs me back to the partition menu and remove the empty spaces (which I can't). I cannot continue with the installation.

I can't figure out what the problem is, and whether it solvable. If someone has encountered this problem, please enlighten me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Try to boot up with your USB, start up gparted there and nuke the partition table completely and create your partitions there or let the installer do this on its own, this should solve your issue.

Comment: Why do you have to format and make partitions manually? Let Ubuntu use the available empty space.

Comment: If an external drive that you want to boot separately you have to partition in advance and include an ESP on external drive, if UEFI. UEFI only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi from external devices. Grub will default install to internal drive and you can boot external from that grub if desired. https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply's. Making a partition with gparted did the trick. Thank you. It only left 1 MB emptyspace before the partition (as compared to 33 MB from partition table).

@mikewhatever: I had a totally empty SSD and wanted Ubuntu to install in it, but for that I have to go to the partition table, otherwise it uninstalls my Windows OS. When trying to install Ubuntu in this partition table, it makes a partition, but leaves 33MB of empty space before the partition, and 10MB after. gparted leaves 1MB before and 0 after. On this partition Ubuntu accepted the installation.