# How to list boot to Windows and Ubuntu, Can't boot to Windows after installing Ubuntu on external drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I installed Ubuntu on an external SSD hard Drive and the main HDD has Windows installed on it.

When I installed Ubuntu on the SSD, it should give me a choice to boot to Ubuntu or to Windows, but the PC boots to Ubuntu directly without giving me any choices to boot to Windows or to Ubuntu...

How can I change that?

> by the way I used Ubuntu and saved important data on it and don't want to lose it or lose the Windows data

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS install? And then did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode. And if full install to external drive in UEFI boot mode, you must partition in advance and include an ESP on external drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: @Omar H. Soliman when you installed Ubuntu on external SSD have you created EFI Partition on it? have you gone to something else screen? if yes, what did you select for "Device for bootloader installation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install rEFInd boot manager package:

```
sudo apt install refind
```

and automatically install the boot manager on the ESP/EFI partition:

```
sudo refind-install
```

or custom (like on a USB stick partition):

```
sudo refind-install --usedefault "/dev/sdX1" # X1 = example: /dev/sdb1
```

and reboot and it boots up auto-discovering all bootable partitions on all drives.

Another tip is to press F12 during startup to open up a bootmenu.

Troubleshoot? Boot a live stick like Ubuntu 18.04. Download and write to a USB stick:

```
dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdx
bs=$((1024**2)) /dev/sdx
```

/dev/sdx being your destination drive like /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc.

Use gnome-disks to open up all your ESP/EFI partitions and check the subdir structure type in terminal:

```
find \`mount | grep vfat | sort | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'\`
```

which could/should look something like:

```
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/ /media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu /media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/fw
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/ubuntu/BOOTX64.CSV
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/drivers_x64/ext4_x64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/README
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/arrow_left.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/arrow_right.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/boot_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/boot_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_about.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_csr_rotate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_exit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_firmware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_hidden.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_reset.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/func_shutdown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/mouse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_arch.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_centos.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_chakra.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_chrome.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_clover.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_crunchbang.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_debian.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_devuan.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_elementary.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_fedora.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_freebsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_frugalware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_gentoo.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_gummiboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_haiku.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_hwtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_kubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_legacy.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_linuxmint.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_lubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_mac.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_mageia.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_mandriva.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_netbsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_network.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_opensuse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_redhat.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_refind.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_refit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_slackware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_suse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_trusty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_ubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_unknown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_win8.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_xenial.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_xubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/os_zesty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_apple_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_fwupdate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_memtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_mok_tool.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_netboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_part.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_shell.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/tool_windows_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/transparent.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/vol_external.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/vol_internal.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/vol_net.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/icons/vol_optical.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/altlinux.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/canonical-uefi-ca.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/centos.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/fedora-ca.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/microsoft-kekca-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/microsoft-pca-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/microsoft-uefica-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/openSUSE-UEFI-CA-Certificate-4096.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/openSUSE-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/refind.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/refind_local.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/keys/SLES-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/refind.conf
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/BOOT/BOOT.CSV /media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/drivers_x64
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/drivers_x64/ext4_x64.efi
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/refind_local.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/refind_local.crt
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/altlinux.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/canonical-uefi-ca.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/centos.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/fedora-ca.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/microsoft-kekca-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/microsoft-pca-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/microsoft-uefica-public.der
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/openSUSE-UEFI-CA-Certificate-4096.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/openSUSE-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/refind.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/keys/SLES-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/README
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/arrow_left.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/arrow_right.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/boot_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/boot_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_about.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_csr_rotate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_exit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_firmware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_hidden.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_reset.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/func_shutdown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/mouse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_arch.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_centos.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_chakra.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_chrome.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_clover.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_crunchbang.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_debian.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_devuan.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_elementary.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_fedora.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_freebsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_frugalware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_gentoo.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_gummiboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_haiku.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_hwtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_kubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_legacy.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_linuxmint.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_lubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_mac.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_mageia.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_mandriva.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_netbsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_network.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_opensuse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_redhat.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_refind.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_refit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_slackware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_suse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_trusty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_ubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_unknown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_win8.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_xenial.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_xubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/os_zesty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_apple_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_fwupdate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_memtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_mok_tool.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_netboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_part.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_shell.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/tool_windows_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/transparent.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/vol_external.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/vol_internal.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/vol_net.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons/vol_optical.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/refind.conf
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/BOOT.CSV
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/README
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/arrow_left.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/arrow_right.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/boot_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/boot_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_about.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_csr_rotate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_exit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_firmware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_hidden.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_reset.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/func_shutdown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/mouse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_arch.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_centos.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_chakra.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_chrome.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_clover.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_crunchbang.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_debian.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_devuan.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_elementary.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_fedora.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_freebsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_frugalware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_gentoo.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_gummiboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_haiku.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_hwtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_kubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_legacy.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_linux.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_linuxmint.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_lubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_mac.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_mageia.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_mandriva.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_netbsd.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_network.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_opensuse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_redhat.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_refind.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_refit.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_slackware.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_suse.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_trusty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_ubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_unknown.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_win.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_win8.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_xenial.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_xubuntu.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/os_zesty.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_apple_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_fwupdate.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_memtest.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_mok_tool.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_netboot.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_part.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_shell.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/tool_windows_rescue.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/transparent.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/vol_external.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/vol_internal.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/vol_net.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/icons-backup/vol_optical.png
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/refind/refind.conf-sample
/media/ron/DB9A-B328/EFI/tools
```

The above refind subdir structure is because I installed rEFInd.

Comment: big Love for you

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

What boots first depends on your BIOS/UEFI boot settings and the configuration of your MBRs.

The BIOS/UEFI lets you choose which drive will boot at first.

1. If you choose USB, the external USB-SSD will be chosen to boot the OS. If the SSD does not have a boot-sector with a bootloader which lets you choose which drive to boot, it will go straight through and boot the OS on the drive (in this case the SSD) and the internal HDD will be ignored.
2. If you choose HDD, the internal HDD will be chosen to boot the OS and the external SSD will probably be ignored.

The best solution would be to install a software/bootloader like `grub` on both drives, the internal HDD and the external SSD, which both should have an option to reference to each other. This way you could always choose which drive (and therefore OS) you want to boot.

This is not easy, but probably well explained in other answers on AskUbuntu answering bootloader problems.

Comment: i have second SSD Hard Drive with the Main Hard drive (HDD) and i connected it to my laptop  not USB drive and  i cannot reinstall Ubuntu as i already saved an important data to it  so how can that happens

Comment: As long as Windows still boots if you disconnect the external drive, you can still access the data on both drives, even if it may not be conveniant. I would **highly** recommend to make a backup of all important data before changing the MBRs with new bootloaders. To many things can go wrong...