# What does "Install alongside Window" do?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I want to install a PC with dual boot. It already has W10 installed on a small SSD, and would like Ubuntu to be installed on a partition my secondary disk, a 1TB HDD.
If I shrink the space on my secondary disk, will the "Install alongside Window Boot Manager" install it on the free space or it will automatically partition the SSD and install it there?

Comment: I would not trust it. Just use Something else.If UEFI often good idea to have an ESP on HDD, even though originally it will not be used. I use it for backup of my ESP on SSD. And then it relatively easily could be set to be bootable,if SSD fails for any reason.UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  Then use Something Else and choose (change button) partitions for / (root) & /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: Related: [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/301745), [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/301745)

Comment: It is UEFI. I already deactivated fast boot, secure boot and all that stuff.