# Ubuntu on Second Drive Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

Hey guy I have been struggling getting a dual boot set up and I could use some help.  I just bought a new computer and the first thing I did was I installed a SSD and installed windows 10 onto it.  So what I am working with is one SSD which has windows 10 and a very large HDD.  I would like to install ubuntu on my HDD and be able to dual boot to it while still using the majority of the HDD for windows home user type stuff.

I have installed ubuntu several times with a few different configurations, but it always will just boot to windows.  The bios does not recognize that the HDD is bootable.  I have tried several different 'step by steps' but none of them are seeming to work.

I have a large RESULTS.txt file that I got from bootinfoscript while using ubuntu from my memory stick to try and resolve this, and I can get you pretty much any other data you need.  Not sure if you want.  The bootinfo is quite large, if you want a section let me know what section to post.

Below is the `fdisk -l`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo fdisk -l Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB,
1864450048 bytes, 3641504 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512
bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size
(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors Units: sectors
of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512
bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors Units: sectors
of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512
bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors Units: sectors
of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512
bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 489.1 GiB, 525112713216 bytes, 1025610768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512
bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
C104C93E-B365-4EF4-A693-02D7584E142D

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type /dev/sda1      34 
262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved /dev/sda2  264192
1025609727 1025345536 488.9G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
D22AC0E3-5C7F-4FEF-BBE5-32DF0FF2FCD5

Device          Start        End  Sectors  Size Type /dev/sdb1       
2048     206847   204800  100M EFI System /dev/sdb2      206848    
239615    32768   16M Microsoft reserved /dev/sdb3  3904931840
3907028991  2097152    1G Windows recovery environment /dev/sdb4     
239616  100239359 99999744 47.7G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/sdc: 14.9 GiB, 16016998400 bytes, 31283200 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x05a7fbb7

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type /dev/sdc1  *    
2048 31283199 31281152 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. Link will show all details including partitioning. Microsoft requires vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode. But user can install in 35 yr old BIOS/MBR configuration.  Did you install in UEFI mode and then also install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S8522ZnP6V/      So far as UEFI boot mode I am not sure.  That is above my level of expertise.  I went with defaults on the windows installation and with the ubuntu installation I selected the 'something else' and selected the sdb with the largest free space, allocating 50gig or so.  Then for the boot option at the bottom I picked the sdb.    The computer is an acer aspire tc-780-ur12 desktop

Comment: Not familiar with grub2win. Looks like an alternative to rEFInd for graphical icons for bootmanger. Boot managers are menu and grub is both bootmanager & boot loader. What brand system? Your Ubuntu entry in UEFI does not look correct. I would from Boot-Repair's advanced options when live installer is booted in UEFI mode, do the full reinstall of grub2. Your Windows install is a bit strange as it is not all on SSD? The ESP - efi system partition is on HDD. Was system set to boot from HDD when you installed Windows so that was where it put ESP?

Comment: oldfred thanks for the help.  The grub2win was an attempt I made at resolving the issue based on typical internetting.   So to answer your last question I would say yes, the system was originally set to boot from HDD.  Now however in the bios there is no option to boot from HDD, only from the SSD and the memory stick.  Post windows install I removed all partitions from the HDD that I could through windows.  Two partitions remained.

Comment: oldfred can you clarify "I would from Boot-Repair's advanced options when live installer is booted in UEFI mode, do the full reinstall of grub2"  How do you boot live installer in UEFI mode?  I assume that is the ubuntu installer?

Comment: You could try disabling `Secure Boot` in your bios. Also, could you please include what hardware you have(specifically we need the motherboard)?

Comment: The mainboard is a Aspire TC-780(KBL).  Secure boot is disabled in the bios.  I tried to do a boot-repair but alias no luck, still loads straight to windows.  Still no second drive showing in the bios for booting options.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I figured it out.  Run CMD as administrator in windows and use this command:

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

This solution was found here:

[This link](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux)