# Dual boot on separate SSDs

Tags: dual-boot

Setting up Zbook 17 G1 laptop with 2 500GB Solid state drives.

Is there any reason why I can't just set up Windows on the C:\ drive then swap the boot drive to D:\ in the BIOS and load Ubuntu?

Can I start with an Ubuntu Image in a USB drive?

Comment: There no difference for the installation one or more drives as long as you know what you're doing. Unfortunately your question shows that you don't. UEFI machine boot from an EFI partition, not drives.

Comment: That is the way you would do it in legacy mode, where you "boot to a disk" which means "load the MBR of this disk". Thinks work differently in EFI mode where you load a file located in the EFI System Partition. Thus your confusion.

Comment: Some more info on UEFI installs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI If you can disconnect or turn off in UEFI the Windows drive, that is easiest. Otherwise you must partition in advance using gpt & include an ESP on second drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: GabrieelaGarcia - All very true..... although you could be a tad more tactful. I am setting the laptop up for my daughter who is interested in programming. mook765 - I rather like the idea of this Legacy mode.