# Dual-boot. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on different drives

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, lenovo, ssd

I have a laptop Lenovo IdeaPad S340. Inside the laptop is the native NVME M.2 and I installed the SSD 2.5. I plan to use Windows for games, Ubuntu for work. I want to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on different drives. When installing Ubuntu, I would like to encrypt the hard drive. I also want to hide a Windows disk from Ubuntu to avoid damaging the file system.
My plan was to disable SSD 2.5 in BIOS and install Windows on NVME M.2. Then disable NVME M.2 and install Ubuntu on SSD 2.5. When I boot, I just select the drive I need. Perhaps for experienced users this seems primitive but it is ideal for me because of it simple. 
But my Lenovo laptop has a limited BIOS with advanced settings disabled, so I cant manage SATA and PCIE configurations. I called Lenovo support and they refused to help me unlock the BIOS.

So here is what I have:

- The BIOS says that plugged SSD 2.5 in SATA port 1, NVME M.2 in PCIE.
- The Windows USB installer defines SSD 2.5 as drive 0, NVME M.2 as
  drive 1
- The Ubuntu USB installer defines NVME M.2 as /dev/nvme0n1, SSD 2.5 as
  SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda) - /dev/sda.

Default settings in the BIOS:

- Boot Mode - Legasy Support
- Boot Priority - UEFI FIRST
- Fast Boot - Enabled
- Secure Boot - Disabled (Unactive, grayout. It only becomes active if
  select Boot Mode - UEFI.)

To be honest, I'm confused.

1. What BIOS settings should I use?
2. Which operating system should I install first and on which drive? I
   ask this because Windows installer define SSD 2.5 as the first disk,
   and Linux installer define NVME M.2 as the first disk.

Please help me find the best solution.

UPDATE:

I decided to install only Windows. Without Linux. This is too hard for me. Thanks to all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) and [Dual Boot on separate drives - best configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-separate-drives-best-configuration)

Comment: Only partially.
I still do not have the answer to the questions: 1) Which operating system should I install first and on which drive? 2) How to encrypt ubuntu for dual-boot? 3) How to hide a Windows disk from Ubuntu to avoid damaging the file system. I published only two questions, but I wanted to get answers based on a description of my situation in the first paragraph. In particular, problems with encryption and hiding of disks.

Comment: Which system are you going to use the most? The NVMe drive is faster than the SSD. If in UEFI settings, you can turn off (disable) a drive it will not matter which you install first, but be sure to install both in UEFI boot mode. My motherboard would only boot in UEFI mode with UEFI only and CSM/Legacy off. But different brands vary. Microsoft so far has required vendors to allow users to turn UEFI Secure boot on/off. If only installing Ubuntu with encryption it will use entire drive using LVM an advanced volume system.

Comment: Most often I will use Windows.

Comment: @oldfred Would you be willing to post that (or something like it) as an answer? I think that answers this specifically, based on largely objective considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which system are you going to use the most? The NVMe drive is faster than the SSD.

If in UEFI settings, you can turn off (disable) a drive it will not matter which you install first, but be sure to install both in UEFI boot mode. My motherboard would only boot in UEFI mode with UEFI only and CSM/Legacy off. But different brands vary.

Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Microsoft so far has required vendors to allow users to turn UEFI Secure boot on/off.

If only installing Ubuntu with encryption it will use entire drive using LVM an advanced volume system.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm