# How to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 on separate drives without deleting data already on the drive Ubuntu is going to be installed on?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have two drives. Drive 1 already has Windows 10 on it and Drive 2 is for personal files and apps. I want to install Ubuntu on Drive 2, but I don't want my existing files on Drive 2 to be deleted. My computer uses UEFI and GPT. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: See if this helps `https://linoxide.com/distros/install-ubuntu-18-04-dual-boot-windows-10/`

Comment: If you unplug Drive 1 during install you can't damage it. When installing use "Something else". Make sure you boot the installer drive UEFI.

Comment: Only use Something Else install option. And make sure Windows fast start up is off, so the Linux NTFS driver can correctly see your NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Be sure to install in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-separate-drives-best-configuration