# Can I install Ubuntu in an HDD when I have Windows 10 in an SDD?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, ssd, storage

I have a laptop that has an HDD and an SDD. In the SSD I have Windows 10 installed, and now, I want to install Ubuntu in the HDD.

Is it possible to do it? And if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install on Second Hard Drive with startup boot option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option)

Comment: Similar: Good advice on UEFI and two drive installs and links to UEFI explanations
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds
Best to partition in advance: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Unplug your Windows SSD, Install Ubuntu on the HDD, (in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows runs in). Plug Windows back in, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have a HDD or SSD is irrelevant.  You can follow any guide to install Ubuntu alongside Windows such as [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)