# Full Ubuntu USB Boot Drive Installation Not Working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, live-usb, bios

For the past couple of weeks, I have been trying to make a full installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my 64 GB USB 3.1 but it hasn't been working. Initially, I successfully installed it on a 32 GB USB 2.0 but it was too slow so I decided to install it on my USB 3.1 by following the same steps. When I did this, at the end it said successfully installed, but when I go to my BIOS, the boot drive isn't showing up there. This didn't happen with the first USB. I tried it multiple times, but none worked.

Here are the steps I followed for installation:

1. Partitioned my USB into two; one 32 GB FAT32 partition and one 25.7 GB FAT32 partition (the remainder)
2. Installed a Live version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a USB using Rufus and an ISO file
3. Booted from the Ubuntu Live USB and clicked Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
4. Selected the language and location
5. Selected "Something else" as the installation option
6. Formatted the 32GB FAT32 partition as an ext4 partition and mounted it with /
7. Started the installation

For some reason, each time I tried installing it, the installation process took over 5 hours, so I just left it to install overnight.

The device I am using to install Ubuntu on the USB with is the HP Envy laptop.

Comment: Writes are what is slow with flash drives. You can change some settings to improve that. But you really should be installing from one USB to another. Good advice on UEFI and two drive installs and links to UEFI explanations
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu from a Pre-built Image File.

Here is a simple method that should not take more than a half hour and should work on any Intel computer with the right spec's.

**If working in Windows:**

- Download Image File: `dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-06-26.img.xz` from mkusb Index of /isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios at
  https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/?C=M;O=D Download Link: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-06-26.img.xz Link to MD5SUM's: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/md5sum.txt.asc
- Download Rufus*: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.11/rufus-3.11.exe
- Etcher may also be used to flash the image: https://www.balena.io/etcher/
- Double click Rufus .exe file.
- Select USB drive as Target drive in Rufus.
- Select above Image File in Rufus.
- Click Rufus start button.
- Wait for flashing to complete... Done.
- Password is "changeme", change it

The USB drive should boot on almost any modern X86-64 computer.

[image]

Thanks to sudodus for the image file.

In Windows it may be necessary to install 7Zip before proceeding. Rufus and Etcher will use it when working with the .xz image: https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe

**If working in Ubuntu:** you can use **mkusb**, **Disks** or **Etcher** to flash the USB drive. P7zip may be needed to extract the image.

Comment: I tried the way you said here, exact step by step, and it installed quickly, but when I was booting from the USB, it got stuck on one of the loading pages. It didn't work. Is there any other way you know?

Comment: Have you tried the USB on another computer? Perhaps there is a hardware problem, Here is another method that works well for me, but it is more complex: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step It also boots on both BIOS and UEFI systems.