# Makeing a bootable internal hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So i wanted to get another machine but with Ubuntu on it, but the problem is that it doesn't have a hard drive. so i grabbed by external had drive made it bootable on my windows machine then that's what i'm using currently, but it doesn't save anything i do after i restart the computer. and when i click power off it doesn't power off the computer. so i grabbed a internal hard drive from an old windows XP machine that i never used, and installed it. i deleted everything off it and now i want to be able to boot off it but i cant find a way to do that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS2Sw.png

Comment: Are you expecting to boot from a empty drive? That's not how it works, you need to install some OS on it.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install. New systems are typically UEFI. If UEFI you want to convert drive to gpt. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-separate-drives-best-configuration Same for any external drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive/1122123#1122123

Comment: First confirm mode Windows boots in. If a newish machine booting Windows 10 it is probably UEFI, If an older machine booting Windows 7 it is likely BIOS. Remove the Windows disk and Install Ubuntu to the second disk in the same mode Windows runs in. Plug the Windows disk back in, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to Ubuntu's boot menu.

Comment: I dont know what this was origenally used for as my mother just brought it home from work one day. she just told me that the hard drives had to stay becuase the company needed them. on the computers they origenally ran windoes 10 pro and dont go straight to bios with no boot drive like normal computers. it just says : 
No hard drive found 

[F1] to try again
[F2] bios
[F3] run diognostic       I also cant hook up the hard drive to my main windoes machine becuase i dont hav the right connectors on the motherboard