Ubuntu disk partion
I want to clean install ubuntu on my pc , I have 128 gb of ssd and 1tb of hdd , I am confused how should i do disk partioning in ubuntu . I want to install only ubuntu on ssd and rest of my data on hdd so that I dont use much of my ssd read and write cycles.
Help me with how much space should I allocate to Wath partion

...search for "separate home partition".

This should get you started https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Similar questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds

For a clean install on one disk with your data on a different physical disk, I start with only the physical disk connected and powered.  On that disk I let the Ubuntu distribution have free rein to wipe out and install as it decides best.  After the basic system has been installed, I would then connect and power another physical disk that would then be configured in
/etc/fstab
